# Protect my database password from developers

Tags: ubuntu, java, postgresql

We have an application that uses a database at my workplace. Currently, it's using a username password to authenticate (though we could use trusted IPs connections). We don't want to use trust because of the movement we will be doing with the IPs for particular machines on which the application and database reside.

Currently, because we apply the username / password set in configuration files in the application, we have the developers in addition to my boss who is the system's administrator and us his six subordinates aware of the password (me being chief), because anyone of us on a rotational basis administrator, maintain and deploy the application. As such, the risk is on all of us to keep the password secure.

**What I have done**
Recently we have started changing the password on a more frequent basis, but I now want only myself to known this password. I am the only one who should run queries on the database directly by directive of my boss. Even my boss has no need to know it off head (maybe in my absence and on record). I have thought of doing below:

1. Create a text file on the server only readable to the application.
2. Have the developers code the application to refer to this file for plain text password.
3. The application use this to login.

I am thinking that the developers will still be able to reveal the password if in the application they store code that does this for them (NOT that they are sinister, we are just trying to collectively streamline collective risk)

**Question**
Is there a better way to perfect this approach, and is there also another way that i may use other than this.

Platforms: Linux (Ubuntu Server), PostgreSQL, Java

Comment: This is pretty much useless, as the devs will always have the chance to do everything the DB credentials allow through their code.

Comment: Environment variables.

Comment: If the file is available for the application, it is VERY available for the developers

Comment: @Sven, the code being used to do things is not the problem...we keep deployment version and so we can trace manipulated code. It's password sharing which I want stopped. This solves half the problem, except that they can reveal the password through code, reading the file.

Comment: I'm thinking of deploying a compiled connection component that they use for connections, and I always compile for a new password

Answer (score 0):

The old unix/linux way is:

```
vi /etc/my_app.conf
database_ip=192.168.123.123
database_instance=db1
database_user=my_app
database_password=secret_in_plaintext
```

This doesn't solve your problem immediately, but... In future you can deploy exactly the same application binaries (war/jar) to **different** application servers (production, preproduction, testing, dev). These all can have different databases (prod, pre, test, dev). This way developers won't need access to production at all, eventually.

Comment: But I will need the devs to not be able to see the creds eventually..